# jQuery click animate move down without class

Tags: jquery

Its quite hard to explain. I have a class as selector, which is clickable. After the click, the class gets removed, so that **it should'nt be clickable anymore, until the class gets added again**.

My code is like this:

```
$('.inactive').click(function(){
     $('.inactive').addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
     $('#test').animate({ top: "+=20" }, 400);
});
```

You can check [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/va54xpkj/)

Comment: It would work properly if you checked for the inactive class. For what you have, the click is bound to the element, removing the class will not unbind the click. You would need to delegate the event, `$(document).on('click', '.inactive', function(){....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Anton said, or...

```
$(document).on('click', '.inactive', function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
        $('#test').animate({ top: "+=20" }, 400);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works the best. While using this method, after adding the class back again the element is still clickable, which, in Antons case, prevents the element from being clicked.

Answer (score 1):

As I get your question, you need to stop this behavior once the class is removed. Despite the fact that you have removed the class, the DOM's click event still has this function attached. Remove it with

```
$(this).off('click');
```

after DOM manipulation.

Edit. I presume, you are using jQuery v.1.7+, else use:

```
$(this).unbind('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

As they are mutually exclusive, you shouldn't need both `inactive` and `active` classes. Either one should do the job - styling and selection.

The simplest way to detach an event handler after the event has fired is to use jQuery's `.one()`.

You will end up with something like this.

```
function activate() {
     $(this).removeClass('inactive');
     $('#test').animate({ top: "+=20" }, 400);
}

$('.inactive').one('click', activate);
```

By defining the handler as a named function, it remains available to be reattched.

To make an element inactive again you would need to add 'inactive' and reattach the click handler :

```
var $foo = $(selector);//select an element or elements by whatever means
$foo.each(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('inactive')) {
        $(this).addClass('inactive').one('click', activate);
    }
});
```